Continuous time-change in Ito diffusions
Recently I read the paper/draft available here: http://www.scse.ca/scse/congres2004/articles/Valery_Gourieroux.pdf
In this paper the Jacobi process is constructed by continuous time-change of a stationary bivariate CIR diffusion $(X_1, X_2)$ with independent components that have the same mean-reversion and volatility parameters. Motivated by the relation between gamma distribution (invariant for CIR diffusion) and beta distribution (invariant for Jacobi diffusion), specific functional relation transforms the process $(X_1, X_2)$ to the process $(Y_1, Y_2)$: $$Y_1=X_1/(X_1+X_2), \quad Y_2=X_1+X_2.$$ Here, $Y_2$ is again CIR process (but with the new driving Brownian motion) and from $Y_1$ the Jacobi process $Y_1^{*}(t) = Y_1(T_t)$ is derived by introducing the absolutely continuous time-change $t \mapsto T_t$ into process $Y_{1}$. Time-change process $T_t$ is defined as the integrated CIR $Y_2$: $$T_t = \int_{0}^{t} Y_2(s) ds.$$ At the end, in the SDE for the resulting process $Y_1^{*}$, the integrals with respect to $T_t$ and the time-changed Brownian motion are again represented as the integrals with respect to the operational (standard) time $t$ and a new time-changed Brownian motion, I guess by the time-change formula for Ito integrals from Oksendal's book SDEs (2003, Theorem 8.5.7, page 156). What confuses me the most is the following:

It seems that after substituting the time change in the integral involving drift, $dT_t$ becomes $Y_2(T_t)dt$ - is it again a special application of the same theorem from Oksendal referenced above?
Does the integrated diffusion (integrated CIR $Y_2$ in this case) as a time-change process destroys the Markovianity, i.e. is the resulting process $Y_{1}^{*}$ still Markovian since this $T_t$ is absolutely continuous time-change, and more, is it again an Ito diffusion, just driven by a new time-changed Brownian motion?

If anyone could help me with some useful references and/or examples and explanations, I would greatly appreciate it.
Cheers!

In that question you should focus on the $Y$ processes as your questions are only about those. Then make it fully self contained not asking someone willing to help to read that paper. So far all one can say is that when $T_t$ is what you wrote it does absolutely not seem that $dT_t$ becomes $Y_2(T_t),dt,.$ It is obviously $dT_t=Y_2(t),dt,.$
